# Animation Nodes: loop list to vertices of a mesh

Tags: mesh, vertices, animation-nodes, loop

I try to make a loop with a spherical mesh and make it loop in a way that each iteration go to the location of respectfully each vertices of a random mesh like suzana the monkey for exemple.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my way by doing like this:

[image]